# Permission error when executing a 5.6 GB sqlcmd file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express, sqlcmd

I am trying to run a very large file through the `sqlcmd` command and it works perfectly with files of 100 MB up to 1.4 GB. This is what I have tested so far, but when I try to run a file which is 5.6 GB, it throws this permission error:

> Sqlcmd: Error: Error occurred while opening or operating on file C:\Test\Insert_Generated_File.sql (Reason: Access is denied).

The error is thrown immediately.

Are there any limitations on SQL Server Express edition when executing large files?

Just so that everything is clear, the file contains `INSERT` generated statements from a 4GB database and nothing more. It is saved as a `*.sql` file.

The version of sql I'm using is:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2269.0 (X64)
>       Jun 10 2015 03:35:45
>       Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
>       Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3  (Build 10586: ) (Hypervisor)

All I want to know is why am I getting that error, is it because of Express Edition, or because sqlcmd cannot handle a file that large. Unfortunately, I do not own a Standard Edition of SQL Server so I cannot test it there.

I know of the SQL Express database limitations, yet I am scripting a database which is already part of my server. It would make sense if I did not have this data already in, but I do. And all the data is already in once. I just cannot recreate it using this file.

Comment: Express Edition is limited in database size. The limitation varies between versions of SQL Server. Also, any error message and relevant schemas are helpful if you want a good answer to your question - use the "edit" link on the lower-left of the question to update.

Comment: Sounds as if `sqlcmd` can't handle files larger than 4GB but I don't think this has something to do with the express edition. Do you have a standard or enterprise edition around to verify that _that_ sqlcmd can open that file?

Answer (score -2):

@Mihai, As  `Daniel Hutmacher` already said,`Express Edition is limited in database size.` As per sqlmag BOL http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-2012/sql-server-2012-express-editions, if you are using `SQL Server Express with Advanced Services`. `It is limited to 4GB and can access only the local instance.`

Even in **dba.stackexchange** the `Shanky` [How many users are supported on SQL Server 2012 Express?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/124422/how-many-users-are-supported-on-sql-server-2012-express) has also explain the limitation of SQL Server Express edition .

Comment: The limitation on the DB size in 2012 is 10 GB, not 4 GB. You've probably confused that with something else.

Comment: @AndriyM, Thanks for reminder. I have clear picture after the post of shanky. I had already asked related to this topic. Even i would like to say at this point "The Reporting Services implementation in SQL Server Express with Advanced Services is limited to 4GB and can access only the local instance."