# Reclaiming unallocated space from tempdb database in SQL Server Express 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need to reclaim space from `tempdb` database which has more than `50 GB` unallocated space. I have tried **DBCC SHRINKDATABASE** but it didn't do anything. Please note, I am aware that it has performance implications but I have no choice. I run SQL Server Express on a laptop and really need this `50 GB space`. Also I have tried restarting SQL Server/laptop and have ensured that no process is running right now.

Comment: Which SQL Server Express version is in your environment?

Comment: It is SQL Server 2012 - Version 11.0.2100.60

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done it using

> DBCC SHRINKFILE ('tempdev',10)

Somehow `DBCC SHRINKDATABASE` was not working. Even `DBCC SHRINKFILE ('tempdev',0)` or `DBCC SHRINKFILE ('tempdev')` doesn't work. We have to assign some figure in MB to which it will shrink the database to.

Comment: From this TSQL code DBCC SHRINKFILE ('tempdev',10). What you are going to shrink (data file or log file).

Comment: The data file was the culprit. Log file was small.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you know the `SQL Server Express` database limitation.As you said `tempdb` which has `50 GB`.  As per **MSDN BOL** [Here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-2017-editions) **SQL Sever Express supports Maximum database size is 10 GB**. And also you can find more `SQL Server 2012` limitation details [Here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/124422/how-many-users-are-supported-on-sql-server-2012-express).

**Note:** Before executing the [DBCC SHRINKDATABASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-shrinkdatabase-transact-sql) or [DBCC SHRINKFILE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-shrinkfile-transact-sql) . You must know their nature of execution.

> To shrink all data and log files for a specific database, execute the
>   `DBCC SHRINKDATABASE` command. To shrink one data or log file at a time
>   for a specific database, execute the `DBCC SHRINKFILE` command.

**DBCC SHRINKDATABASE**

***Shrinks the size of the data and log files in the specified database***

Shrinking a database and specifying a percentage of free space

The following example decreases the size of the data and log files in the `UserDB` user database to allow for `10 percent free space` in the database

```
DBCC SHRINKDATABASE (UserDB, 10);  
GO
```

**Truncating a database**

The following example shrinks the data and log files in the AdventureWorks sample database to the last allocated extent.

```
DBCC SHRINKDATABASE (AdventureWorks2012, TRUNCATEONLY);
```

**DBCC SHRINKFILE**

***Shrinking a data file to a specified target size***

The following example shrinks the size of a data file named `DataFile1` in the UserDB user database to `7 MB`.

```
USE UserDB;  
GO  
DBCC SHRINKFILE (DataFile1, 7);  
GO
```

***Shrinking a log file to a specified target size***

The following example shrinks the log file in the AdventureWorks database to 1 MB. To allow the DBCC SHRINKFILE command to shrink the file, the file is first truncated by setting the database recovery model to SIMPLE.

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;  
GO  
-- Truncate the log by changing the database recovery model to SIMPLE.  
ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks2012  
SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;  
GO  
-- Shrink the truncated log file to 1 MB.  
DBCC SHRINKFILE (AdventureWorks2012_Log, 1);  
GO  
-- Reset the database recovery model.  
ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks2012  
SET RECOVERY FULL;  
GO
```

***Truncating a data file***

The following example truncates the primary data file in the AdventureWorks database. The sys.database_files catalog view is queried to obtain the file_id of the data file.

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;  
GO  
SELECT file_id, name  
FROM sys.database_files;  
GO  
DBCC SHRINKFILE (1, TRUNCATEONLY);
```

> **Note:** You can reduce the default size of an empty file by using DBCC SHRINKFILE target_size. For example, if you create a 5-MB file
>   and then shrink the file to 3 MB while the file is still empty, the
>   default file size is set to 3 MB. This applies only to empty files
>   that have never contained data.

Before execute the DBCC SHRINKFILE , As `Mike Walsh` explained very well you must know [Here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29829/why-does-the-transaction-log-keep-growing-or-run-out-of-space/29830#29830) that, is it really necessarily to run that command.

For further your ref [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169634/limitations-of-sql-server-express)

Comment: Thank You. Yes. Express has limitation of 10 GB per database. Yet Tempdb was at 50 GB. May be the the limit is only for user databases and not system databases.

Answer (score 0):

If tempdb did not shrink even after instance restart, then probably initial size is too big. 
Please try shrink using DBCC SHRINKFILE to get some space.

```
USE [tempdb]
GO
DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'tempdev' , 0, TRUNCATEONLY)
GO
```

Comment: Nopes, Initial size was 10 MB. It ballooned to 50 GB after I ran a bad query with incorrect join thus returning a lot more rows than I wanted.